# Why Fmtflags are specified twice - once as part of an enum, and another instance as a static const variable

Tags: c++, std

In the STD library file ios_base.h we see the following:

```
  enum _Ios_Fmtflags 
{ 
  _S_boolalpha  = 1L << 0,
  _S_dec        = 1L << 1,
  _S_fixed      = 1L << 2,
  _S_hex        = 1L << 3,
  _S_internal   = 1L << 4,
  _S_left       = 1L << 5,
  _S_oct        = 1L << 6,
  _S_right      = 1L << 7,
  _S_scientific     = 1L << 8,
  _S_showbase   = 1L << 9,
  _S_showpoint  = 1L << 10,
  _S_showpos    = 1L << 11,
  _S_skipws     = 1L << 12,
  _S_unitbuf    = 1L << 13,
  _S_uppercase  = 1L << 14,
  _S_adjustfield    = _S_left | _S_right | _S_internal,
  _S_basefield  = _S_dec | _S_oct | _S_hex,
  _S_floatfield     = _S_scientific | _S_fixed,
  _S_ios_fmtflags_end = 1L << 16 
};
```

But after that we also see:

```
    /// Insert/extract @c bool in alphabetic rather than numeric format.
static const fmtflags boolalpha =   _S_boolalpha;

/// Converts integer input or generates integer output in decimal base.
static const fmtflags dec =         _S_dec;

/// Generate floating-point output in fixed-point notation.
static const fmtflags fixed =       _S_fixed;

/// Converts integer input or generates integer output in hexadecimal base.
static const fmtflags hex =         _S_hex;
```

Why are they using static const in addition to the enum values to represent the same values? Why can't we just use the enum values? And isn't using static wasteful in this case considering those are const values?

Thanks,
Ofer

Comment: The enums look like they're only for internal use.

Comment: It's probably for type compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to separate the interface and implementation. `_Ios_Fmtflags` is implementation-defined and can be changed in the future, `ios_base` should not be significantly dependent on `_Ios_Fmtflags`, but must provide a set of constants as part of the documented interface [see comment](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/77e36160e50f241bfd2f1b5be82b33b88c749408/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h#L297). How could we avoid code dependency on the internal `_Ios_Fmtflags` implementation? We can use synonyms for `_Ios_Fmtflags` type and constant objects of this type which is done further:

```
typedef _Ios_Fmtflags fmtflags;
static const fmtflags boolalpha = _S_boolalpha;
static const fmtflags dec =         _S_dec;
```

Now only these lines depend on the specific  `_Ios_Fmtflags` implementation. For example, we can rename `_S_boolalpha` and it will not affect the code except only one line `static const fmtflags boolalpha = _S_boolalpha;` Or as another example, we can replace `enum _Ios_Fmtflags` by integer or some else suitable type. A very useful technique that makes the code maintaining much easier, although it increases the code size.